# How to ship to multiple addresses using the Magento API (cart)

Tags: api, soap-api-v2, shipping-address, multishipping, soap-api-v1

I would like to be able to ship to multiple addresses on the same order using the Magento API. Is this functionality using the Magento API available? Or it is only available using the web interface?

Answer (score 0):

Magento support has confirmed that this is not possible using the native API (At least in version 1.9 and 1.14)